# Collision probability when using ranges with random start point compared to all random id's

Tags: probability

When generating universally unique identifiers, it's common to use random 128bit integers. This allows each member of a distributed system to generate new id's without asking if it's already been used, with basically zero chance of collision. This unfortunately makes sets of uuid's quite hard to both compress and index efficiently. Same applies to maps with uuid keys.

Another way of generating random id's would be to randomly pick a start point for each node, and then sequentially increment from there for future id's. What I don't know is how long these segments should be before picking a new random starting point and continuing from there.

Since each client has their own random starting point for the first id, it's exactly the same scenario as above when the run length is $1$, so that's known to be good. Having longer segments makes it much easier to index and compress, but I have a feeling it would impact the collision probability.  Having the run length equal the keyspace is also known to be good, for a single client. This is just an auto incrementing id field. For multiple client, this gives a 100% chance of a collision happening.

What's the probability of collision when using `r`-length sequential runs of id's, with a random starting point, for `i` id's (keys) and a `k` bit keyspace?

Comment: Interesting that we don't seem to have a "hashing" tag here, though I believe there are a good number of posts dealing with at least [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) [related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) applications?

Answer (score 0):

If we use a run length $r = 2^x$ we can divide the keyspace into $2^{k-x}$ blocks of size $2^x$ and then compute the birthday paradox as usual.

If $i^2$, the number of id's squared, is much smaller than the keyspace, [we can approximate the collision rate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884002/17857) by $\frac{i^2}{2*2^k}$ when $i^2 \ll 2^k$.

If we group id's into $r=2^x$-length blocks of sequential numbers, [we get this new collision rate](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B(m%2F2%5Ex)%5E2%7D%2F%7B2*2%5E%7Bk-x%7D%7D):

$$\frac{{(\frac{i}{2^x}})^2}{2*2^{k-x}} = \frac{i^2}{2^{k+x+1}}$$

which has the interesting property that it decreases as $x$ increases. The bigger block size we use, the lower the chance of a collision, at least if the blocks are filled completely with id's, and aligned to a power of two. The real mystery now is, why isn't everyone using blocks of sequential uuid's?